# WebGrid content column suddenly not wrapping

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I suddenly have a very annoying issue and I have no idea how it came about.

I am using this code to generate a table in my view:

```
@{ 
    var grid = new WebGrid( Model, rowsPerPage: 100);
    var columns = new List<WebGridColumn>()
    {
        grid.Column("LeadId", FormLabels.ResourceManager.GetString("ID")),
        grid.Column("Date", FormLabels.ResourceManager.GetString("Date"),
                format: (item) => string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", item.Date)),
        grid.Column("Location", FormLabels.ResourceManager.GetString("Location")),
        grid.Column("Name", FormLabels.ResourceManager.GetString("ContactName")),
        grid.Column("Organisation", FormLabels.ResourceManager.GetString("Organisation")),
        grid.Column("Details", FormLabels.ResourceManager.GetString("LeadDetails"))
    };
}

<div class="container">
    <h2>@Headers.ResourceManager.GetString("Opportunities")</h2>

    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "table selectableGrid",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alternate",
        columns: columns,
        htmlAttributes: new { data_selecturl=Url.Action("Details", "lead") } )
</div>
```

And this has always worked to produce a table like this:

[image]

But suddenyly, when debugging my project, it now looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the final column text is extending outside of the `"continer" div` and no longer wraps.

I can confirm that the html is identical, and I can't see any difference in the computed css when inspecing in Firefox.

I am pretty much 100% sure I didn't change any css rules before this starteed happening, which I know seems impossible, but I have no idea what could have caused this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can find the culprit, or how to just solve the wrapping issue?

Thank you

#### What I already tried

I set `table-layout:fixed` on the `table`, but this fixes all columns to be the same width, so that is not the issue.

#### html

1.

```
<div class="container">

    <h2>Opportunities</h2>

        <table class="table selectableGrid" data-selecturl="/en-US/lead/Details">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=LeadId&amp;sortdir=ASC">ID</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=Date&amp;sortdir=ASC">Date</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=Location&amp;sortdir=ASC">Location</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=Name&amp;sortdir=ASC">Contact Name</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=Organisation&amp;sortdir=ASC">Organisation</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=Details&amp;sortdir=ASC">Details</a>            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>    
            <td>7</td>
            <td>20-09-2017</td>
            <td>testerton</td>
            <td>testy mcgee</td>
            <td>test llc</td>
            <td>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alternate">
            <td>8</td>
            <td>20-09-2017</td>
            <td>testerton</td>
            <td>testy mcgee</td>
            <td>test llc</td>
            <td>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

2.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Opportunities</h2>

        <table class="table selectableGrid" data-selecturl="/en-US/lead/Details">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=LeadId&amp;sortdir=ASC">ID</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=Date&amp;sortdir=ASC">Date</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=Location&amp;sortdir=ASC">Location</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=Name&amp;sortdir=ASC">Contact Name</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=Organisation&amp;sortdir=ASC">Organisation</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/en-US/Lead?sort=Details&amp;sortdir=ASC">Details</a>            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>20-09-2017</td>
            <td>testerton</td>
            <td>testy mcgee</td>
            <td>test llc</td>
            <td>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alternate">
            <td>8</td>
            <td>20-09-2017</td>
            <td>testerton</td>
            <td>testy mcgee</td>
            <td>test llc</td>
            <td>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was actually that one of the rows contained a very long string in the `Details` column with no spaces.

This was stretching out the column for that row, and doing the same for all other rows.

I could fix this with

```
table td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all
}
```

but this causes the other rows to shrink to the size of the header row, meaning dates appeaer as:

```
01-0
1-20
00
```

So to resolve this, I applied it only to the last column with

```
table tr td:last-child {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all
}
```

Annoyingly, this doesn't seem to work in Edge or Chrome, where the date column still breaks as above.